# How can I copy the elements from a util:list to another one using Spring's xml

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 2.5 , and the idea would be something like:

```
<util:list id="europe" >
    <ref bean="France" />
    <ref bean="England" />
    <ref bean="Spain" />
</util:list>

<util:list id="america" >
    <ref bean="Mexico" />
    <ref bean="Brazil" />
    <ref bean="USA" />
</util:list>

<util:list id="world" >
       <!-- copy elements from list "europe" -->
       <!-- copy elements from list "america" -->
</util:list>
```

is it possible ?

Comment: That is not possible with `util` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is not supported out the box.

For Spring 2.5 you could do something like

```
<bean id="tmpList" class="org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils"
    factory-method="union">

    <constructor-arg ref="europe" />
    <constructor-arg ref="america" />   
</bean>

<bean id="world" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceList" ref="tmpList" />
</bean>
```

And since 3.0 (with Spel)

```
<bean id="world" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceList" 
        value="#{ T(org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils).union(@europe, @america) }" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can I autowired it like this in java class :   @Autowired
@Qualifier("world")
private ListFactoryBean listFactoryBean;


listFactoryBean.getObjects();

Comment: List<Object> = listFactoryBean.createInstance();